# Firefox html - Strange grey line between rows

Tags: html, firefox

Check out this HTML code:

```
<table width="90%" align=center cellspacing=1 rules=rows cellpadding=5 style="border: solid 2px black;" bgcolor="#000">
    <tr style="background-color: brown;">
        <td width="100%">row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: blue;">
        <td width="100%">row2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Works fine in Chrome but for some reason in Firefox it adds grey lines between each row. I don't know why but I don't want them, any idea how to rid?

EDIT: When I put the html in JSFiddle or snippet it doesn't add them. Pasting the code into a blank page and running does.

Comment: Can you make a snippet here. Does it add there?

Comment: Doesn't add with snippet either

Comment: Use a CSS reset. https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

Comment: Is this supposed to be HTML5? what is it's DOCTYPE? rules property is not supported in HTML5 [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_rules.asp) but as I can see Firefox adds rules even when I use <!DOCTYPE html>